How do you type a function that returns a function with different parameters
I have an outer function that takes a string as an argument that then returns a function that uses that string. The return function takes either a string or an array of strings as an argument. If it receives an array, it returns an array. If it receives a string it returns an object. How can I make TypeScript recognize that the return function can take either argument and return the appropriate type without having to assert the return type every time I use it.
Here's a simplified, contrived example of what I'm trying to accomplish and things I've tried:
function outer<T extends { arg: string }>(arg: string): (id: string) => T;
function outer<T extends { arg: string }>(arg: string): (id: string[]) => T[];
function outer<T extends { arg: string }, S extends string | string[]>(arg: string): S extends string ? (id: string) => T : (id: string[]) => T[];

function outer<T extends { arg: string }>(arg: string): (id: string | string[]) => T | T[] {
  return (id: string | string[]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(id)) {
      return [{ arg }] as T[];
    }

    return { arg } as T;
  }
}

type ArgType = { arg: string };

const result = outer<ArgType>('arg')(['id']);

Playground.
I get the following error when trying to pass in an array:
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.


Simplified example:
type T = { arg: string }

declare function outer(arg: string):
    <S extends string | string[]>(id: S) => S extends string[] ? T[] : T

const resultScalar: T = outer('arg')('id')
const resultArray: T[] = outer('arg')(['id'])

The type parameter S goes on the returned function, not the outer function.
T doesn't need to be a type parameter, unless you're using it elsewhere. You should probably rename it now it's just a normal type, but I've kept the name here just to show the correspondence with your code.
